# Linear Programming - Basic solution

Tags: optimization

I'm reading some notes [Linear Programming](http://people.math.aau.dk/~cornean/advanced_optimization_11/LP.pdf) on linear programming. I'm considering the standard minimum problem. Why is it so obvious that, if $-\textbf{c}\geq \textbf{0}$ and $\textbf{b}\geq \textbf{0}$, then minimum occurs at $\textbf{y}=\textbf{0}$ and $\textbf{s}=-\textbf{c}$ ? I see that, when $\textbf{s}=-\textbf{c}$ then $\textbf{y}=\textbf{0}$ must be true. I'm confused why $\textbf{b}\geq \textbf{0}$ is neccecary. Thank you in advance.

$\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
  & s_1 & s_2 & \cdots & s_n &  \\ 
\hline
 y_1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 \\ 
 y_2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
 \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots &  & \vdots  & \vdots \\
 y_m & a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} & b_m \\
\hline
 1 & -c_1 & -c_2 & \cdots & -c_n & 0 \\ 
\end{array}$

Don't math.exchange support tabulars? Or what am I doing wrong ? It's se same table as the one on page 20 in the hyperlink.

Comment: Tabular:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2016/73324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any term of $\mathbf{b}$ is negative, we might make the corresponding term of $\mathbf{y}$ grow without bound -- hence there is no minimum to $\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: And if, $-\textbf{c}\geq \textbf{0}$ then $\textbf{c}\leq \textbf{0}$. This ensures that when $\textbf{y}=\textbf{0}$ the constraint $\textbf{y}^{T}A\geq \textbf{c}^{T}$ are preserved. Right ?